# Calculate from an array in memory

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to VBA but understand the basics. My question is as follows:

I need to divide the individual cells of an array with its corresponding offset cell (E3/E2, F3/F2, G3/G2, etc.) and store it in an array. Then, I need to find the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd smallest numbers of that array and highlight the cell in the first row of that column. Here is what I have:

```
Option Base 1

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Private Sub test5()

    Dim row As Integer
    Dim column As Integer
    Dim myArray(10) As Double
    Dim myArray1(3) As String
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    Dim intQuizNumber As Integer
    Dim intTestNumber As Integer
    Dim intProjectNumber As Integer


    intQuizNumber = 3
    intTestNumber = 3
    intProjectNumber = 3

    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Range("D3"), Range("D3").End(xlDown))) Is Nothing Then

        Range("1:1").Interior.Color = xlNone
        row = ActiveCell.row
        column = ActiveCell.column

        For a = 1 To 10
            myArray(a) = Cells(row, column + 1) / Cells(2, column + 1)
            column = column + 1
        Next a

        row = ActiveCell.row
        column = ActiveCell.column

        'Evaluate("=RANK(E3,$E$3:$N$3,0)+COUNTIF($E$3:E3,E3)-1")
        For b = 1 To 3
            myArray1(b) = Evaluate("=CELL(""address"",OFFSET(" & Target.Offset(0, 1).Address & ",0,MATCH(SMALL(" & Target.Offset(0, 1).Address & ":" & Target.Offset(0, 3 + 3 + 3 + 1).Address & "," & b & ")," & Target.Offset(0, 1).Address & ":" & Target.Offset(0, 3 + 3 + 3 + 1).Address & ",0)-1))")
        Next b

        Union(Range(myArray1(1)).Offset(-row + 1, 0), Range(myArray1(2)).Offset(-row + 1, 0), Range(myArray1(3)).Offset(-row + 1, 0)).Interior.Color = 65535

    Else
        Range("1:1").Interior.Color = xlNone
    End If

End Sub
```

I would like to replace the Evaluate statement in "b" loop with the one that I have commented out but can't seem to do it. I first need the value of the division and then I need to get the three lowest and highlight the cells. I've searched on Google thoroughly and can't figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to use RANK instead of what you have, but here's another way to get what you want.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim vaNums As Variant, vaDenoms As Variant, aDivs() As Double
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim lSmall As Long
    Dim rRow As Range
    Dim rStart As Range

    Const lCOLS As Long = 10
    Const lMARKCNT As Long = 3

    If Not Intersect(Target.Cells(1), Me.Range("D3", Me.Range("D3").End(xlDown))) Is Nothing Then

        Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction ' this just makes our code easier to read

        'If these ever change, you only have to change them in one place
        Set rRow = Target.Cells(1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, lCOLS)
        Set rStart = Me.Cells(1, 5)

        'Clear existing colors
        rStart.Resize(1, lCOLS).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

        'Read the current line and the 2nd line into arrays
        'This shortcut creates two-dimensional arrays
        vaNums = rRow.Value
        vaDenoms = rStart.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, lCOLS).Value

        'Do the division and store it in aDivs()
        ReDim aDivs(LBound(vaNums, 2) To UBound(vaNums, 2))
        For i = LBound(vaNums, 2) To UBound(vaNums, 2)
            aDivs(i) = vaNums(1, i) / vaDenoms(1, i)  + (i / 10000)
        Next i

        'Find the nth smallest value and gets its position with MATCH
        'Then use that position to color the cell
        For i = 1 To 3
            lSmall = wf.Match(wf.Small(aDivs, i), aDivs, False)
            rStart.Offset(0, lSmall - 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        Next i

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll try that out and let you know. I wanted to use RANK instead because it will give me the three lowest values even if all three are the same. Right now if I have (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1) all being divided by 30, it returns only the first two. RANK + COUNTIF will give me a separate ranking of duplicates.

Comment: Okay, I tried it out and it looks like yours gives me the same result as mine. It doesn't highlight the second "1". Any way I can implement the RANK + COUNTIF? Or if there is another solution I'm more than open to it. Thanks!!

Comment: Ah, you are quite right. I've changed the code to add a very small number to the end of each number before it finds the smallest values. This worked for me with duplicates.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't what you mean by "add a very small number to the end of each number."

Comment: I included the line `vaNums(1, i) = vaNums(1, i) + (i / 10000)` that adds a very small (but unique) number to every number in vaNums. If there are two numbers that are the same, adding this small number makes them different.

Comment: Is there any way I can get the three lowest from the calculated values in the array? It seems to give me the three lowest from the values in the third row and not from the calculated values of the division.

Comment: For example: Row 3 = 1,2,3,4,5  Row 4 = 10,10,10,10,50  1/10 = .1 2/10 = .2 3/10 = .3 4/10 = .4 5/50 = .1 The result should return First, Second, and Fifth (even though Fifth is the highest score, it has the lowest average).

Comment: You just use aDivs in the Small formula rather than aNums. Plus you have to add that tiny value to aDivs to make them all unique. I updated the code to reflect this.